# Saving and retrieving Data directly from angularJs

Tags: angularjs, database-connection, single-page-application

I have a simple application that keeps record of entry and exit(in time format). I have made the application run locally for a single day. But I need is that it should keep record of previous days as well and help me perform some calculations of monthly basis.

1. So my question is can I directly connect to DB from angularjs? If yes, how and which DB?
2. Is there some other way in which I can achieve the same result, without using any DB?

Comment: As of now  Firebase is one of the  powerfull real-time db which can be used with Angular JS directly.Have a look into this article.https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

Comment: Simplest option - [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
Other option, which is supported all modern browsers, - [Indexed DB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Comment: @synh localStorage won't keep data once, the browser window is closed so I cannot use it for later calculations